# Android, небольшой фикс бага с разметкой

Tags: java, android, xml, recyclerview

Как пофиксить такой баг, когда список залазит на элементы, что снизу? Не могу понять, как правильно сделать .. 
Вот разметка:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.project.samuliak.psychogram.Activity.main.menu.common_items.CommunicationActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_mes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_mes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_rectangle"
            android:text="@string/send"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Вот скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

МОжет поставить списку маржин? Или это не самый лучший вариант ?

**UPDATE2**

В принципе маржин помогает ... но кажется мне, что это не по госту )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/rv_mes"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout10" />
```

Comment: Точно!! Спасибо,) из головы вылетала данный параметр!

Comment: Пожалуйста))))...